# Next upcoming date model object ignoring past dates

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to utilise `latest()` on a django model queryset to return the next upcoming date in a model.

I've tried a few different things, using `__lte` and `__gte` lookups on a filter and to no avail.

The filter option would work for me, if there was a way to effectively utilise a model method within an `exclude()` but without writing a custom manager that's not going to be an option.

There must be an easier way?

```
class RaidSession(models.Model):
    scheduled = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()

    def is_expired(self):
        duration_to_date = self.scheduled + self.duration
        return True if duration_to_date < timezone.now() else False
```

Comment: Could you post the attempt via `filter` as well?

Comment: Let me try to paraphrase your requirement: You want the first model object in a list sorted by date filtered by objects later than the current date plus some duration from the respective model field?

Comment: @dhke the duration for this query set isn't important. Just the scheduled datetime once .now() is later than that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm a little old school, it usually helps me to think of such problems as an SQL query. In your case this would be

```
SELECT * FROM app_raidsession rs
    WHERE rs.scheduled >= now()
    ORDER BY rs.scheduled
    LIMIT 1
```

This gives you the next scheduled raid.

In django ORM, you should be able to translate this more or less straightforward to:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

# first() returns None if the result is empty
next_raid = models.RaidSession.objects \
    .filter(scheduled__gte=now()) \
    .order_by('scheduled') \
    .first()
```

If the duration is relevant, you will need an [F-expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters):

```
from django.db.models import F

next_raid = models.RaidSession.objects \
    .filter(scheduled__gte=now() - F('duration')) \
    .order_by('scheduled') \
    .first()
```

Comment: Beautifully done, I love it how you analysed it in SQL first, handy debugging tool.  (PS `.filter(scheduled__gte==now())` should be only one = :).  This works a treat.

Comment: Nah, I though I edited that double `==` out already. Fixed, thanks.